# C# WinForms TreeView & ImageList

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, imagelist

I have treeview and 2 imagelist first image list contains images only 42x42 and second 36x36 first for roots and second for childs. does it possible to choose 2 imagelist for treeview

so... Second question : I have users which adding by admin. I now how to create child nodes when users is added but how can i add in current root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TreeView only supports selecting an image from a single ImageList.  You can combine the two ImageList instances into a new one that is 42x42, but that may not render very well.

I *Think* I understand your second question.  Set the TreeView.ShowRootLines value to false and then just add nodes to the TreeView.Nodes collection.